# unable to start nginx on debian 8 jessie

Tags: nginx

```
> root  21:18  /l/s/system  > service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.


> root  21:18  /l/s/system  > systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-08-21 21:18:32 IST; 1min 14s ago
  Process: 10539 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10537 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 21 21:18:29 patchy nginx[10539]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 21 21:18:30 patchy nginx[10539]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 21 21:18:30 patchy nginx[10539]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 21 21:18:31 patchy nginx[10539]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 21 21:18:31 patchy nginx[10539]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 21 21:18:32 patchy nginx[10539]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Aug 21 21:18:32 patchy systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 21 21:18:32 patchy systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Aug 21 21:18:32 patchy systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
root  21:19  /l/s/system  >
```

and

```
root  21:24  /l/s/system  > nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

> root  21:24  /l/s/system  > nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
root  21:24  /l/s/system  >  netstat -tupln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1091/exim4      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59497           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      604/rpc.statd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      554/rpcbind     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2917/tor        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      645/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1091/exim4      
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      554/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::35157                :::*                    LISTEN      604/rpc.statd   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      645/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8118                :::*                    LISTEN      644/privoxy     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:700             0.0.0.0:*                           554/rpcbind     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:780           0.0.0.0:*                           604/rpc.statd   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:64640           0.0.0.0:*                           1840/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           7586/chromium   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           672/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30267           0.0.0.0:*                           1900/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                           727/minissdpd   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1900/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1840/dhclient   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           554/rpcbind     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53560           0.0.0.0:*                           604/rpc.statd   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51528           0.0.0.0:*                           672/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::49807                :::*                                672/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::700                  :::*                                554/rpcbind     
udp6       0      0 :::60292                :::*                                604/rpc.statd   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                672/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::30267                :::*                                1840/dhclient   
udp6       0      0 :::7942                 :::*                                1900/dhclient   
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                554/rpcbind     
root  21:25  /l/s/system  >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `[emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)`

and

> `tcp 0  0 127.0.0.1:8080  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  2917/tor`

shows the problem: you are running Tor on the port that you are trying to start Nginx on. You will need to reconfigure one of these processes to use a different port.